# How to restrict folder access in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security

How to restrict folder access in asp.net
like I don't want any other to see my Uploads folder in browser by link  http://www.example.com/Uploads

Comment: The default settings for this should be non browsable

Answer (score 64):

For the future generation the answer which works for me is to use hidden segments.

If you want to secure e.g. *Uploads* folder go to your root Web.config and add into `<system.webServer>` following element:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="Uploads"/>
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

This will prevent all users from direct access to *Uploads* folder and its content.

Comment: Very usefull, this works perfect if your site don't has roles or authentication

Comment: Very interesting. The Microsoft documentation is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments/ . It says this mechanism is used to protect the bin and app_code paths.

Comment: Please also note that this will protect sub directories "inadvertently". So if you have `<add segment="plugins"/>` then the path `/assets/javascript/plugins/myfile.js` will be restricted.

Answer (score 23):

You can do like @klausbyskov mentions, to add `<authorization />`'s to the root web.config, like:

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrator"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

or you can add a web.config to the folder where you want to allow/deny access with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrator"/>
            <deny users="*" />              
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Of course replace the `<allow />` and `<deny />` with you own rules

Comment: None of them work for me (using MVC4). I see most of posts suggesting this <location> thing, but I have added it at root, inside each folder I need secure, tested local and on server... it never works... am I missing something? Uisng MVC 4.

Comment: +1 for having the full text i could copy and paste into a new web.config i created on a hot server.

Comment: Will these rules be applied to all subfolders as well? Or do I have to add a web.config to each folder? And does it apply to all file types?

Comment: @Nestor I was also not able to get it to work until I found that you need to add <remove  name="UrlAuthorization" />
<add  name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule"  /> under <system.webServer> <modules>

Answer (score 4):

You should add a web.config file to said folder and put an `<authorization>` tag in the file, as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

You can manage folder browsing in IIS settings.,

- Open IIS Manager and navigate to the folder you want to manage.
- In Features View, double-click Directory Browsing.
- In the Actions pane, click Enable/Disable.

This is for IIS7.

you can also use commandline for this.

```
 appcmd set config /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true|false
```

Hope this helps...
Happy Programming,