# restrict accessing Image directly through URL ASP.Net from a particular Folder

Tags: asp.net

I am having a website developed with ASP.Net(4.0). I am having Jpeg images maintained in a Folder. I would like to restrict the users from directly accessing the images through url access(Like: "http://www.example.com/images/latest/a123g.jpg"). But, I am showing these images in lightbox from a particular page.

In addition, I would like to restrict the particular folder images from displaying in Google Image search. Kindly Guide me.

Thanks in advance!
Thirumalaisamy.P

Answer (score 0):

For restricting users from directly accessing your images through url, you will need to use hidden segments in your `web.config` file, as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776847/how-to-restrict-folder-access-in-asp-net).