# ASP.net Authentication on Generated Link

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security

One of our ASP web apps has a button, that generates a expiring link to a form. We have noticed that anyone with said link can view the form. I am researching a way to have the end-user be checked for authorization when the link is opened up. Ask them for their username/password before they can view the link.

my sub that generates the link:

```
Protected Sub ButtonLink_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim strSQL As String = ""
    Dim wapguid As String = ""
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    wapguid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO [WapCustomerAccess] (wapid, wapguid, expires, generatedBy) values (@wapid, @wapguid, @expires, @generatedBy)"

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wapid", WAPID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", wapguid)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@generatedBy", Session.Item("UserFullName"))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expires", Date.Now.AddDays(31).ToString)

    Dim strConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cnnCFHSWAP").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
    cmd.Connection = con

    Try
      con.Open()
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
    Response.Write(ex.Message & "<br />")
    Finally
      con.Close()
      con.Dispose()
    End Try

    Dim t As New TextBox()
    t.Text = "http://wap-test.cfhs.local/secure/waplink.aspx?SSL=true&hash=" & WAPID & "&guid=" & wapguid & "&expires=45&suid=05A2FF&salt=x00FF&enc=true"
    t.ID = "txtLink"
    t.Width = 800
    t.ReadOnly = True
    t.BackColor = Drawing.Color.SeaShell

    PanelLink.Visible = True
    PanelLink.Controls.AddAt(0, t)
    PanelLink.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))

End Sub
```

Comment: When i go to a page but need to log in i get a url like this: `https://mywebsite.com/log-in.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin%2f`. Try something like that. Send to the login page with the query string you create for that user. (?)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to restrict access to `waplink.aspx` in the app that is referred to in your generated links. Depending on that app, you will find suitable tutorials for setting up authentication/authorization, like [1].

[1] https://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config

Comment: ah ok, I see. I am now trying to figure out how to restrict access to folder (called "private") that contains waplink.aspx require all users to enter in their username and password to open. I tried to do so in Web.config with location path="private", which did not work.

Comment: Is general authorization already set up in the app? Did you try the tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776847/how-to-restrict-folder-access-in-asp-net)?